# Designing a quadrotor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys,

So I'm new to gazebo (and any 3D simulator software package for that matter) and have been going through the tutorials (which are immensely helpful) to familiarize myself with how the program works. In my project I am required to make use of multiple quadcopters (not any particular model) but I could not find one in the Gazebo model repository. Could someone kindly indicate from where I could find such a model or how I should go about designing one for myself (this is not a requirement so if there is a ready model which I couldn't find that would be great)?

Thanks a lot in advance
JP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3248/designing-a-quadrotor/) by [jpcallus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/391/jpcallus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I know that some people use [this quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor) in Gazebo, maybe the link helps to look further.

Cheers

UPDATE!!

[here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) are the ROS tutorials

and [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/ros_enabled_model_plugin) gazebo ros integration example plugin

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpcallus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/391/jpcallus/) on 2013-06-20**:
Thanks for your reply. Since i'm new to Gazebo i'm not yet sure as to how ROS integration works (or how ROS works for that matter). Is there some sort of tutorial you could point out to familiarize myself? Cheers

**Comment by [jpcallus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/391/jpcallus/) on 2013-06-20**:
Awesome! I'll take a shot at that cheers mate :)